# How can i add or change text to a <div> element from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am trying to create a program that takes whatever text you input and (for now) shows it in a  element.

Here is what i have of code:
HTML:

```
 <body>
     <center><h1><b>J.A.I.</b></h1>
     <!--dialogue-->
     <div id= "dialogue"></div>
     <!--input-->
     <input id="text" type='text'></input>
 </center>
 </body>
```

Javascript:

```
 //takes input from <input type=text>
 function takeInput() {
     var question = this.value;
     displayOutput(question, output);
 }

 //displays output
 //@param message string Message to be displayed
 //@param destination HTML element where the message is to be displayed
 function displayOutput(message, destination) {
     destination.innerHTML = message;
 }

 //init code

 var input = document.getElementById("text");

 var output = document.getElementById("dialogue");

 input.onkeydown = takeInput();
```

I am using firefox 31.4.0 and the error i get says:

> TypeError: destination is null

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the space before the equals? `<div id="dialogue"></div>` not `<div id= "dialogue"></div>`

Comment: please remember to accept an answer if your question has been answered, or update it with more information if it hasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you are using "text" as an id name, and it is reserved. Don't use it as an ID. Also, i have chosen to bind the function in the HTML. So change it to:

```
<input id="txtField" type='text' onkeyup="takeInput()"></input>
```

And change the JS to get that ID as well:

```
var input = document.getElementById("txtField");
```

Here is a working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6t4pkn3j/11/

Note, in my JSFiddle i moved some code around. I find it more clean to gather everything in functions and not leave those global variables hanging around :)

Hope it helps.
/JBJ

*** EDIT ***
Seems 'text' is not a reserved word after all :-) The issue probably laid with event binding then (second part of my answer). Here is a new JSFiddle that uses 'text' as an id:
https://jsfiddle.net/6t4pkn3j/12/

Answer (score 0):

You need to *assign* the function to the event:

```
input.onkeydown = takeInput;
```

You were immediately calling the function instead.